# suggestion for the way for storing multimedia belong to different users

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata, scalability, multimedia

What's the best way more scalable way to do that.

Currently my database is Mysql and i am using php in my website. But It is just a demo. But I want to ensure the way i store multimedia resource is scalable with manageable accessibility.

The simple way is storing links in database of multimedia.

Another way is creating specific folder for each user's multimedia and put the media in his or her own folder.

And Some other simple way. But I need an expert's suggestion.

Any other Suggested architecture would be appreciated! 
If you know link, website, Publication which can help me let me know.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I already participated in 3 Online courses and studied their books and even I got certificate with distinctions in these course, I asked for suggestions of expert as mentor, @Ohgodwhy you are so negative person, anyway thanks for your time to read my question, Thanks to anyone who is more positive and like a mentor to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate folder and store multimedia in the folder. For detailed answer follow these links:-

- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
- [Storing images in DB vs in Folder Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371297/storing-images-in-db-vs-in-folder-structure)